# is there a way i can edit particle mesh texture?

Tags: mesh, texturing, particles, shader-nodes

I use the particle instance modifier on a texture mesh, and then i apply the modifier. But now, i wanna edit the the texture to make it a bit darker. I've open the shader tab, but theres only the principle bsdf in there. Ive tried playing around with it, it doesnt work.(i thought about mixing the texture with MixRGB node, but there is no texture connect to the principle bsdf)
What would you guys suggest i do?

Answer (score 0):

Combine your Principled BSDF and a Black Emission BSDF through a Mix shader. The mix factor will control the "darkening":

[image: Mix]